# Mocha test of REST API

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm testing a REST API, where the data just comes from a JSON file in the project.

When i test the post method, some of my other test now fails. Because there now is one more object in the array.

What would be the best approach to setup in a before/beforeEach, so the array is the same state in every other test that runs.

Thanks.

```
  describe("GET-methods: ", function () {

    it("should provide 9 users:", function (done) {
        request({method: 'GET', url: URL, json: true}, function (err, res, body) {
            if(err) throw err;
            body.should.have.length(9);
            done();
        });
    });

    it("should find password given email", function (done) {
        request({method: 'GET', url: URL+"/lorem@ipsum.com", json: true}, function (err, res, body) {
            if(err) throw err;
            body.password.should.equal("8F1E-3218-AC06800CA5AC");
            done();
        });
    });
});

 describe("POST-methods: ", function () {

    var newUser = {email: "a@b.dk", password: "secret"};
    var options = {method: "POST",url : URL, body : newUser,json: true};
    before(function(done){
        request(options,function(err, status, body){
            if(err) throw err;
            done();
        });
    });

   it("should find the new user", function (done) {
        request({method: 'GET', uri: URL+"/a@b.dk", json: true}, function (err, res, body) {
            if(err) throw err;
            body.password.should.equal("secret");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't couple your test preconditions or organize your test only on the web service method type.

I think the best way is to organize the tests on **scenarios**, and validate your services on each possible scenario, is more clear to understand what's happening when a test fail, should expect a similar structure like this:

```
describe('given there are no registered users',func...
  //Test your methods when there are no users
);


describe('given there are registered user',function(){
  var mockedUsers = [....];
  beforEach(function preconditionWithUser(){
    // init Current users, Don't edit the mock clone it
    var currentUsers = _.cloneDeep(mockedUsers);
  })

  afterEach(function restoreconditions(){
    // restore users
    // restore Spys, Stubs and other Mocks
  })

  describe('getUsers() should return the currentUsers',func..)

  describe('addUser() should return the currentUsers + new user',func..)

  describe('removeUser() should return the currentUsers -1',func..)
});
```